# rotate/point with sub-pixel precision

Tags: processing

How may I get sub-pixel precision in position of the points plotted below? Only integer precision is used -- causing the observed wobble of the moving points.

```java
int amount = 300;
float[] x = new float[amount];
float[] y = new float[amount];
float[] z = new float[amount];

void setup() {
  size(500, 400, P3D);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    x[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
    y[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
    z[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width/2, height/2);

  rotateX(-0.1);
  rotateY((frameCount/1000)*1);

  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    point(x[i], y[i]/22, z[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the same problem as your other question. You're using integer division, which truncates the decimal part.

This line:

```java
rotateY((frameCount/1000)*1);
```

Needs to be this:

```java
rotateY((frameCount/1000.0)*1);
```

For future reference, problems like these are easily spotted through some debugging. You need to go through your program and test every assumption you're making. In other words, **print everything out**. For example:

```java
println(frameCount/1000);
```

That line would have shown you your entire problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that that change made no visible improvement at all.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Umm, are you sure? Running your code with that change works perfectly for me.

Comment: @ChrisJJ There is one other change you might need. The lines that use `float(random(-150, 150));` do not compile for me, since the value returned from `random()` is already a `float`, so passing it into the `float()` function isn't valid. Just make those lines use `random(-150, 150);` instead, without the `float()` part.