# Web version of processing.exe V3.0.2

Tags: processing

Where can I find a web version of processing compatible with 3.0.2?

http://funprogramming.org/77-A-3D-rotating-cloud-of-points.html is not e.g.

```java
x[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
```

on web doesn't give the parseFloat() error that processing.exe does.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says that questions asking us where to find tools, libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic here. See the section with the numbered list on that page, specifically item #4 in that list.

Comment: Actually it does not. It says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a... ". This question is neither.

Comment: Actually, it is: *Where can I find* are the first five words of your post.

Comment: "Where can I find" is not "asking us to find". It is directed at those who have already found.

Comment: No. Where can I find is directly asking for directions where to find. You can't say "I'm a guy, and I'm not asking for direcfions, but when you went from here to this other place the last time how did you go?* without having actually asked for directions, no matter how vehemently you deny it. Asking where to find the web version is asking for a link to an off-site resource, which is specifically mentioned as being off-topic here i the link I posted.

Comment: "Where can I find is directly asking for directions where to find" Agreed. Not "asking us where to find" it.

Comment: I'm not debating it with you, so you can stop trying to play games with semantics. You asked *Where can I find*, and that's a request for a link to an off-site resource. The question is off-topic, and I've voted to close as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available yet.

There was a link to an experimental version available [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/11928/javascript-mode-removed), but it hasn't been officially released.

You're probably better off just fixing whatever little inconsistencies you find for now.

I'm not sure the code you posted is an inconsistency between versions though. Notice that the original code on the page is this:

```java
x[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
y[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
z[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
```

But your'e doing this:

```java
x[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
y[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
z[i] = float(random(-150, 150));
```

The value returned from the `random()` function is **already** a `float` value, so passing it into the `float()` function doesn't make any sense. That's why you're getting a compilation error.

The web version doesn't complain because it's not as strict with types. But it's not really an inconsistency with Processing 3, it's an inconsistency between Java and JavaScript. That inconsistency is going to exist in every version of Processing.

If you want those values to be `floats`, you can just drop the `float()` part, since they're already `float` values:

```java
x[i] = random(-150, 150);
y[i] = random(-150, 150);
z[i] = random(-150, 150);
```

This is what I was trying to get at in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213167/rotate-point-with-sub-pixel-precision/36220537#36220537) to your other question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. "it's not really an inconsistency with Processing 3, it's an inconsistency between Java and JavaScript" Sad to hear Processing 3 is not consistent across implementations.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I understand what you're saying, but this "inconsistency" is what makes the different modes of Processing interesting and useful. JavaScript and Java are designed for completely different things, so they're going to have a bunch of differences. This is far from the only one. And that's a **good thing**, otherwise there wouldn't really be a point to having multiple modes. [Here](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#thingstoknowusingpjs) is a list of **some** of the differences.

Comment: Thanks for that perspective, but you can drop those scare quotes. :-)